# multiple forms on one page using bootstrap, ajax and external php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have these two form that I want to use both on one page without a refresh. The html,validator and the php is working, but it seems to be ignoring this js file to execute the ajax and load messages on the page.How  do I write an if statement? Or what are other suggestions to get if one form is filled out to execute this code?

[Full Form execution](http://jschro15.aisites.com/anotherWorkingForm/index.html)

[contact.js File](http://jschro15.aisites.com/anotherWorkingForm/contact.js)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question rather than linking to an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('submit', '#contact-form', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

       // your ajax call
});
```

Comment: @JenniferSchroeder np

Answer (score 0):

you are using `.on()` event onot correctly you have to use it like

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

       // your ajax call
}
```

instead  of `$('#contact-form').on('#submit', function (e) { }`

have a look at your script again.

Comment: Add this line as well - if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) { e.preventDefault();

Comment: it doesn't need because at last he has used `return false` so, no need to use this.